# How to auto complete a variable

Tags: php, variables, autocomplete

Once I haven`t typed in all of the characters of one of the variables it shows this

> nl,net,com

But if I typed in the letter "n" after the DOT, I want it to show the variables that begin with a "n":

> nl,net

How to do that?

```
$a = array("nl", "net", "com");

$q = $_GET["q"];

$domain = explode(".", $q);

if (in_array($domain[1], $a)) {
    echo $q;
} else {
    echo implode(',',$a);
}
```

Comment: Is it full php or you want to display them in a page or other? The list of term will be in a static array or they will be fetch from database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This checks using `strstr()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php

As an example input, I have typed part of `asdf.net`, namely `asdf.n`, so `.nl` and `.net` should match:

> UPDATE: It now handles having no extension typed in yet, code now tested with `$q = 'asdf.';` without the n on the end.

```
<?php

$a = ['nl','net','com'];
$q = 'asdf.';

$domain = explode(".", $q);
$ext = $domain[1] ?: '';

if (empty($ext)) {
    echo implode(',',$a);
} else if (in_array($ext, $a)) {
    echo $q;
} else {
    $r = [];
    foreach ($a as $x) {
        if (strstr($x, $ext)) {
            $r[] = $x;
        }
    }
    echo (count($r)) ? implode(',',$r) : implode(',',$a);
}
```

https://3v4l.org/Or3fk

The advantage over the other answer here is it will check as many characters as required, whereas in the other answer it only checks the first letter.

Comment: It works only after the I typed in the dot this appears 3 times: strstr(): Empty needle in D:\school\logica\htdocs\compleet it\domain.php on line 14

Comment: ah yeah well spotted, let me tweak

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over your array and compare the first character of the string with the first exploded value.

```
$a = array("nl", "net", "com");
$domain = explode(".", '.n');
foreach($a as $c) {
    if($c[0] == $domain[1]) {
    //if(substr($c, 0, strlen($domain[1])) == $domain[1]) { or this $domain can be multiple characters
        $matches[]= $c;
    }
}
if(!empty($matches)) {
    echo implode(',', $matches);
} else {
    echo 'no matches';
}
```

https://3v4l.org/sIkjg

Comment: This will only work for the first letter, and autocomplete will break upon the second. i.e if I type `blah.nl`, your code would still return `net`

Comment: @delboy1978uk Use the commented line and it works fine for multiple characters. https://3v4l.org/NU8TH Also when did it return `net`, the single match should return none.

Answer (score 0):

[in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) will return true if and only if the whole value of the needle is present in the array. If your values cannot contain comma, then you can use

```
$a = array("nl", "net", "com");

$q = $_GET["q"];

$imploded = implode(",", $a);

$domain = explode(".", $q);

if (strpos($imploded, $a) !== false) {
    echo $q;
} else {
    echo $imploded;
}
```

Otherwise, if we cannot assume such a thing, you can do something like this:

```
$a = array("nl", "net", "com");

$q = $_GET["q"];

$domain = explode(".", $q);

$found = false;

for ($index = 0; $index < count($a), $index++) {
    if (strpos($a[$index], $domain[1]) !== false) {
        $found = true;
    }
}

if ($found) {
    echo $q;
} else {
    echo implode(',',$a);
}
```